# floating Action button not displaying in rotation of screen

Tags: android-layout

I have added recyclerview as well as floating action button but when i rotate the screen in mobile floating button is not visible only recyclerview is visible.how to make it visible.My Code is as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#DCDCDC">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/CustomerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nextToThird"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorgreen"
        android:src="@drawable/right"
        android:layout_marginStart="260dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:padding="0dp"/>
  
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use relative layout it will work in both orientation landscape and portrait 
like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/activity_main"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.ncrypted.fontdemo.MainActivity">

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/CustomerList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFF" />

 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/nextToThird"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

ask me in case of any query